# plugging battery against the power supply

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics

This may come across as a rather nonsensical question however I think it is worth asking simply to understand what happened.

I plugged in an electric car battery directly to a wall socket, almost immediately there was a significant explosion in the wall socket. There was a power shut down in the entire house.

The battery was fully charged, and I was not using the cable to charge the battery, I was using the cable that is utilized for distributing power.

Basically, I pit the battery own power against the wall socket.

To make a simpler analogy, imagine an external portable battery, the ones that are used for charging electronic devices. The cable has two ends, one that is utilized for charging the battery. Then you invert the side of the cable to charge the device.

Same reasoning happened with the car battery, rather than plugging the battery to charge in the wall socket. (because it was fully charged) I plugged in the other side that distributes power. Then, there was an explosion and a shut down. why?

Comment: You can't be serious. This is a joke, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Darwin Awards website is http://www.darwinawards.com/.

Comment: what do you mean by Darwin Awards ? I tried this at home.

Comment: Don't. Don't do this sort of thing _ever_ again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LMAO firstly I hope you are ok. Secondly what were you thinking? Thirdly it is because 12v car battery, 120v+ in your house. Fourthly there was no regulation for the power. touch the two terminals of the car battery onto a metal fence outside using a piece of wire on each terminal of the battery you will get the same effect but obviously on a much smaller scale. Fithly as above, A.C. D.C.
 May I ask, what were you trying to achieve?

Comment: I see, so essentially what happened was I placed two same type currents going against each other which caused the explosion.

Comment: The explosion was caused by the massive electrical charge that was allowed to travel by you shorting out the plug socket with the battery. Like lightening but inside your house, and not as severe.

Comment: OK - when you say that "shorting out a car battery will get the same effect but obviously on a much smaller scale" Absolutely not - This will very likely cause the battery to explode, spraying hot acid everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You need to educate yourself on the basics of AC and DC electronics before you:

1. Hurt yourself.
2. Hurt somebody else
3. Burn the house down.

You could have very easily caused the battery to explode, splashing battery acid all over you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the obvious, you think I have not after the incident read about this? this site is not meant for being a mom it is meant for answering a question straight foward.

Comment: You don't need your mom to tell you not to stick things in mains sockets. At least, not if you are old enough to form a question about it here. If you are curious, why not ask first?

Comment: @jdv well you do have a point, though I do not understand why there has been a lot of hostility towards the question. It looks to me that it was based on personal bias and not on the site best interest. It was a genuine question, there was an experiment, experiment yielded results I was curious about said results so I attempted to elaborate on all that the experiment had

Comment: I think you are over-reacting. 2/3 answers explained exactly what went wrong, and how it could have gone more wrong, with only some gentle ribbing. Comments are comments, and are mostly reactions to the perception that your attitude was "this should work like I think it ought to work". That perception may be wrong, but that is how it comes across. This combination is not going to get you much more than quick answers and a some snark. No one here appreciates this type of "experimentation" because it isn't really a good experiment.

Comment: Here is a good place to start for safety and explosion risks of a car battery. http://www.geeksoncars.com/info_8154278_causes-batteries-explode.html

Answer (score 2):

The battery is approximately a short circuit as far as AC is concerned.

Just be thankful the "explosion" was in the wall and your house breakers/fuses shut down rather than in the battery, spraying hot sulphuric acid all over your face.

Get the house wiring checked and where necessary replaced by a suitably expensive electrician before replacing fuses or resetting breakers. It'll be cheaper than the mess the Fire Brigade will make.